# QGIS: why does simplesvg export plugin generate poor quality output?

Tags: qgis, export, svg

I am exporting a QGIS project to SVG via the simplesvg plugin. However the output is of really poor quality: all coordinates appear to have snapped to a rather coarse grid (while original data, as shown in QGIS main window, have not). Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin, but it may be helpful to know what coordinate system/projection your data is in. It sounds like a rounding/precision issue at first glance...

Comment: I already wrote problem and workaround here below, this is a self-answered question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the simplesvg plugin exporting window (not in a very evident position, though), simplesvg works by dumping screen coordinates (expressed in integer pixels) from the current viewport at the moment of exporting. This means that all vertices are implicitly snapped to the pixel grid.

A workaround for exporting a large area while still retaining good precision is to zoom in heavily and ask simplesvg to export all data (not only visible data), by unchecking the appropriate checkbox. This will still snap vertices to a grid, but you can make it as fine as you want.